# How do I update my ROM to the CyanogenMOD M series releases using the internal updater?

Tags: cyanogenmod, ota-update

All versions of CyanogenMOD released it the last couple years have an internal over-the-air style ROM update mechanism found under *Settings > About Phone > CyanogenMOD updates*. Using the *Update types* setting you can select whether you want to see only stable updates or nightly builds.

However, these two release lines are not the only options one might want to install. Notably absent is the ability to select the [M series](http://www.droid-life.com/2012/09/11/cyanogenmod-announces-the-m-series-builds-not-quite-a-nightly-but-not-quite-a-release-candidate/) of releases. Technically these are basically milestone tags in the nightly line, but using them [is recommended over nightlies](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/cm-10-1-m-series-builds-have-arrived) for some users.

The M series builds do show up in the updater under the nightly list when they are first built, however that list seems to only show the latest three available builds. **How can I select the most recent M build for installation after three or more nightlies have been built after the M build is released?**

For example, [CM 11 M2 was released](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/cyanogenmod-11-0-m2-release) earlier this month, but I was traveling and now over a week has passed and the updater on my devices only show the nightlies from the past couple days. Please note that I know how to [download the files for my device](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/) and flash them manually, but I would like to use the built in tool.